# How to change the connection string in web.config to use SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to change `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;` in

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StopeAndShopDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\StopeAndShopDB.mdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to use SQL Server 2012 and attach my database to SQL Server instead of `(LocalDb)\v11.0;` but no luck so any help and many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you connect to SS2012 with SSMS?

Comment: Check out [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for a bunch of examples of connecting to SQL Server (and a lot of other databases).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using SQL Server 2012 instead of SQL Server 2012 LocalDb?

Comment: i'm trying to use business intelligence in visual studied so when build my project it give me a error that tell me the server (LocalDb)\v11.0 is not connected and the build fail so i change it to sql server and it build